# Calculating the covariance of two random variables

Tags: probability, covariance

I have 4 random variables:

$X\sim Pois(6)$

$Y \sim Geom (\frac{1}{4})$

$Z=6X-Y$

$U=2X-1$

What is the covariance of X and Y if Cov(Z,U)=0?

What I did:

$Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$, I know $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ as well, I only need $E(XY)$

From $Cov(Z,U)=E(ZU)-E(Z) E(U)=0$, and I know $E(Z)=32$ and $E(U)=11$

$E(ZU)=E([6X-Y][2X-1])=32\cdot 11$

I expanded the expression and got $E(XY)=60$

So $Cov(X,Y)=60-24=36$

Is that right? I generated such X,Y, U and Z in R, but didn't get this 36 covariance.

Comment: Did you happen to simulate X and Y as draws from their respective distributions? If so, then that is not correct, as it implicitly assumes that X and Y are independent, when in fact they are not.

Comment: BTW: Your calculation of the covariance is correct.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 yes, I simulated them from their distributions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your response to my comment, your simulation did not capture the true behavior of X and Y, since you modeled them as independent when they are not independent. This is the source of your numerical error. The theoretically calculated covariance is correct though (36). Simulation of correlated variables with arbitrary marginals is an intermediate/advanced topic, involving copulas and other techniques for inducing the correct relationships.